# Returning more than one column between two criteria

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an SQLite database containing three columns; EmpName, theTime, and theDate. I'm trying to run a query that will return rows with EmpName and theTime that fit a specific range of dates. My goal is to add all these times up and give an end-of-week total time. However, when I run my code, it returns a list of 0.

I've tried queries such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Swipes WHERE theDate>=:starting<=:endof", {'starting': fstartingDate, 'endof': formatted}
```

and

```
SELECT EmpName AND theTime FROM Swipes WHERE theDate >=? <=?, (fstartingdate, formatted,)
```

and

```
SELECT EmpName AND theTime FROM Swipes WHERE thedate BETWEEN ? AND ?", (fstartingDate, formatted)
```

and other variations of that approach, but it feels like I'm running in circles. 
This is my code:

```
def weekSummary(endofthatweek):
    formatted = dt.strptime(endofthatweek, '%Y-%m-%d')
    startingDate = formatted - td(days=7)
    fstartingDate = startingDate.date()
    con = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\zstrickland.RANDSMACHINE\Documents\PymeClock\testTimeclock.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT EmpName AND theTime FROM Swipes WHERE theDate>=:starting<=:endof", {'starting': fstartingDate, 'endof': formatted})
    tupes = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    detuped = [x[0] for x in tupes]
    print(detuped)
```

I hope to get a list(Probably a list of tuples..) in the following format:
[(EmpName, theTime), (EmpName, theTime), (EmpName, theTime), (EmpName, theTime)].
Any help or suggestions on how to make this calculation would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These conditions:

```
theDate>=:starting<=:endof
```

and:

```
theDate >=? <=?
```

are not valid SQL conditions.
You need `BETWEEN`:

```
theDate BETWEEN :starting AND :endof
```

or:

```
theDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: I've also tried this but it just returns a list of 0. Edited my question to reflect this

Comment: If the dates in the table have a comparable format like YYYY-MM-DD and you compare them with similar formatted dates and still get 0 rows, then you have no rows between the date limits you set.

Comment: I've put these values in myself on a dummy database for testing. The range I'm using is 2019-10-13 through 2019-10-20, and I've stored dates spanning from the 10th through the 25th. I know they exist, in the YYYY-MM-DD format. The number of 0s will correspond with how many entries there are, so I'm certain it sees them, but it just returns 0s.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bKGW3brYwrDufdRXCp9bC/0 If the values are ok then the code with BETWEEN should work

Comment: Yes, it will work for one column when I change it to * or either "EmpName" or "theTime", but I would like the values of both EmpName and theTime paired together if they're within the date range. ex. (Zac Strick, 13:22:32). putting a * instead of querying "EmpName AND theTime" just yields EmpName, which is only half my battle.

Comment: What do you mean? What is `EmpName AND theTime`? You want the rows where theDate is between 2 dates. It doesn't make any difference if you write: `select * from Swipes where theDate between....` or ``select EmpName, theTime, theDate from Swipes where theDate between....``

Comment: EmpName is Employee name, the first column in the db. theTime is the time they swiped their card, in a "HH:MM:SS" format. I want to query entries between the two dates and get a list of values containing both EmpName and theTime. The goal here is to get a list of times with the corresponding names so I can run it into more code that will tell me how many hours a certain individual worked in a week.

Comment: This is what `select * ...` does. It returns **all** the columns and the condition in the where clause restricts the rows to the ones that satisfy the condition. Here you set a condition only for the column `theDate`. So all rows between the date limits you set for `theDate`will be returned. If you want additional conditions you must extend the WHERE clause.

Comment: I agree, that's how it's worked for me in the past, but that's why I'm here; SOMETHING in my code is stopping it from returning BOTH values. My current query only returns EmpNames for some reason, even if I put a *. What I posted is the only bit of code I have that's running this query. The function is called upon in a front end script where it asks the user to enter the ending date of the week and then it runs from there. It SHOULD have been working by now, I'm not sure why it returns [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: Current query: cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Swipes WHERE theDate BETWEEN :starting AND :endof", {'starting': fstartingDate, 'endof': formatted}) returns a list of names only.

Comment: I can't help you with the Python code, only with SQL. If the statement you have is valid for Python it should return the correct results.